# Inserting concatenate Identity column with other column

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2012

```
I have a identity column and i have other column while inserting a new row in 
 table i need to insert into third column with concatenate of two columns result
```

For reference please see below table

```
------------------------------------------------
 A    |   B   |  c  
----------------------------------------------
 1    |  33   |   133(1 [identity result] + 33)    
 2    |  112  |   2112
```

Please help me to solve this issue.

Comment: Google for computed columns in MSSQL. ALTER TABLE myTable ADD c AS CONVERT(INT,CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),A)+CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),B));

Comment: Here A  is Identity(1,1)  while inserting new row i need to get A value

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is already an answer to this question but i think is not the best way to achieve it.

Here's an example on how to achieve it with a [computed column](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191250%28v=sql.105%29.aspx).

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.calculatedTEST (
    A INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    B INT NOT NULL,
    c AS CONVERT(INT,CONVERT(VARCHAR(max),A)+CONVERT(VARCHAR(max),B))
)

insert into dbo.calculatedTEST 
(B)
values
(1),
(1),
(2),
(2)

select * from dbo.calculatedTEST
```

> A computed column is computed from an expression that can use other
> columns in the same table. The expression can be a noncomputed column
> name, constant, function, and any combination of these connected by
> one or more operators. The expression cannot be a subquery.
>
> Unless otherwise specified, computed columns are virtual columns that
> are not physically stored in the table. Their values are recalculated
> every time they are referenced in a query. The Database Engine uses
> the PERSISTED keyword in the CREATE TABLE and ALTER TABLE statements
> to physically store computed columns in the table. Their values are
> updated when any columns that are part of their calculation change. By
> marking a computed column as PERSISTED, you can create an index on a
> computed column that is deterministic but not precise. Additionally,
> if a computed column references a CLR function, the Database Engine
> cannot verify whether the function is truly deterministic. In this
> case, the computed column must be PERSISTED so that indexes can be
> created on it. For more information, see Creating Indexes on Computed
> Columns.

Comment: +1
Yes, it is.
will you please explain this??
c AS CONVERT(INT,CONVERT(VARCHAR(max),A)+CONVERT(VARCHAR(max),B))

Comment: @user3540365 added some info from the article on microsoft reference and linked the article.

Comment: Converting numeric values into string values enables the SQL Engine to concatenate them without any error and without sum mathematical process

Comment: But in my case table is already defined and i need to insert into that table.

Answer (score 0):

Don't need to insert Column C, You can easily get Column C using Select Statement.

like this.

```
select A,B,cast(Cast(A as varchar(max))+cast(B as varchar(max)) as 
varchar(max)) as C from Your_Table_Name
```

If you really need to insert column C, then you have to run insert and Update query at the same time to inset value in the C column of the table.

Like:

```
 insert into Table_Name(B) values('33');Select IDENT_CURRENT();
 --you'll get the inserted Identity.
--now run the Update query for Identity you get from the insert query.
```

Sample.

```
 create table #tab1
 (
 Id bigint identity(1,1) primary key,
 a int,
 b varchar(50)
 )

insert into #tab1(a) values(88);
declare @id1 as bigint set @id1=(select SCOPE_IDENTITY());
update #tab1 set b=cast(id as varchar(max))+cast(a as varchar(max)) where Id=@id1
```

Comment: Insert into tbl_test(B,C) values(122,"Here i need to get Identity value of A"+122)

Comment: I should insert value in C in my case its already predefined table.

Comment: then you have to run the update query after getting the Inserted identity value using SCOPE_IDENTITY().

Comment: Ref .
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/103610/Difference-between-IDENTITY-SCOPE-IDENTITY-IDENT-C

Comment: i know that way but i need to check whether it can be done  in single statement ..

Comment: Thank you dude i got solution   i.e   insert into test(B,C) values(122, convert(varchar,IDENT_CURRENT('test'))+'122')

Comment: See the Sample Code.
i just added to my solution.

Comment: Scope_Identity() will return the last identity which is for all tables, But in my i need the last identity of current Table case Ident_Current('TableName'))